# DB Table not creating on submit of form: Magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: magento-1.9, forms, adminform, query, table

I have form in admin created by custom module i created the function to auto create the table in Database if not exists but it is not working to me as follows:

```
    <?php
    $installer = $this; //Getting Installer Class Object In A Variable
    $installer->startSetup();
    $installer->run("
    -- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('optfirst_reviewmycompany')};
      CREATE TABLE {$this->getTable('optfirst_reviewmycompany')} (
      `id_optfirst_reviewmycompany` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
      `facebook` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
      `twitter` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
      `google` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
      `linkedin` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
      `yelp` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
      `piintrest` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
      `gmaps` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
      `bing` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
      `coc` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
      `city_search` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
      `ezlocal` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
      `local` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
      `mcircle` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
      `show_me_local` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
      `superpages` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
      `topix` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
      `uscity` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
      `where_to_app` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
      `yellow_bot` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
      `yellow_wise` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
      PRIMARY KEY (`id_optfirst_reviewmycompany`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
    ");
    $installer->endSetup();
   ?>
```

[image]

here is the config.xml file:

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <optfirst_reviewmycompany>
            <class>OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany_Block</class>
        </optfirst_reviewmycompany>
        <reviews>
        <class>OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany_Block</class>
        </reviews>
    </blocks>

    <helpers>
        <optfirst_reviewmycompany>
            <class>OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany_Helper</class>
        </optfirst_reviewmycompany>
    </helpers>

    <models>         
        <optfirst_reviewmycompany>
            <class>OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>optfirst_reviewmycompany_resource</resourceModel>
        </optfirst_reviewmycompany>
        <optfirst_reviewmycompany_resource>
            <class>OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany_Model_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                <review>
                    <table>optfirst_reviewmycompany</table>
                </review>
                <contacts>
                    <table>optfirst_contacts</table>
                </contacts>
            </entities>
        </optfirst_reviewmycompany_resource>
    </models>

    <resource>
        <optfirst_reviewmycompany_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </optfirst_reviewmycompany_setup>
        <optfirst_reviewmycompany_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </optfirst_reviewmycompany_write>
        <optfirst_reviewmycompany_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </optfirst_reviewmycompany_read>
    </resource>
</global>
```

Comment: double-dash comment maybe make trouble ?

Comment: What's happen if you run your creation query directly in SQL ?

Comment: I have manually added record first and now it saved the data to table whenever i submit the form

Comment: But the issue with table creation is still there

Comment: @Xabby add the `config.xml` and full path of install file

Comment: @Qaisar Satti added the confix.xml please check it now

Comment: flush all magento cache  and check DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add it after `</model>`

```
    <resources>
        <reviewmycompany_setup>
        <setup>
            <module>Optfirst_Reviewmycompany</module>
        </setup>
        <connection>
            <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
        </reviewmycompany_setup>
        <reviewmycompany_write>
        <connection>
            <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
        </reviewmycompany_write>
        <reviewmycompany_read>
        <connection>
            <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
        </reviewmycompany_read>
    </resources>
```

and you installation file path will be `1.0.0` this is current your module version.

```
  modelfolder/sql/reviewmycompany_setup/install-1.0.0.php
```

Comment: Currently i have install file as  app\code\community\OptFirst\ReviewMyCompany\sql\reviewmycompany_setup\mysql4-install-1.0.0.php

Comment: is it wrong anyway? @Qaisar Satti

Comment: aslo remove entry from `core_resource` table of you module `reviewmycompany_setup`

Comment: Just tell me about the file directory that i have mentioned is that wrong and i have to follow your one as mentioned?
   app/code/community/OptFirst/ReviewMyCompany/Model/sql/reviewmycompany_setup/install-1.0.0.php

Comment: i did not see you resource tag configuration first share that then i i can say something

Comment: ok check the config now updated the question

Comment: this is correct path `app/code/community/OptFirst/ReviewMyCompany/sql/optfirst_reviewmycompany_setup/inst‌​all-1.0.0.php` 
aslo remove module entry from `core_resource` table of you module `optfirst_reviewmycompany_setup`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50378/discussion-between-xabby-and-qaisar-satti).

Comment: There were already install for the module in "core_resource" i have removed it and run the script still not creating the table
 optfirst_reviewmycompany_setup  1.0.0  1.0.0

Comment: Satti 
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento_new.new_optfirst_reviewmycompany' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `new_optfirst_reviewmycompany`.* FROM `new_optfirst_reviewmycompany` WHERE (`new_optfirst_reviewmycompany`.`id_optfirst_reviewmycompany`=1)

Comment: @Xabby where you define module version `1.0.0`?

Comment: in config.xml
<modules>
        <OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany>
    </modules>

Answer (score 0):

Try with :

```
<?php
$installer = $this; //Getting Installer Class Object In A Variable
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->run("
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {$this->getTable('optfirst_reviewmycompany')} (
  `id_optfirst_reviewmycompany` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `facebook` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `twitter` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `google` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `linkedin` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `yelp` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `piintrest` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `gmaps` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `bing` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `coc` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `city_search` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `ezlocal` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `local` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `mcircle` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `show_me_local` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `superpages` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `topix` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `uscity` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `where_to_app` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `yellow_bot` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `yellow_wise` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_optfirst_reviewmycompany`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
");
$installer->endSetup();
```

?>

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento_new.new_optfirst_reviewmycompany' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `new_optfirst_reviewmycompany`.* FROM `new_optfirst_reviewmycompany` WHERE (`new_optfirst_reviewmycompany`.`id_optfirst_reviewmycompany`=1)

Comment: Gives this error @Nolwennig

Comment: You create `optfirst_reviewmycompany` table and you request `new_optfirst_reviewmycompany` table. Add `new_` in table name in your creation query or remove it in your request query.

Comment: But new_ is the prefix of the database

Comment: DATABASE name is magento_new and prefix is new_ check the attached image with question now

Comment: So what will my syntax in this case? @Nolwennig